# Trying to limit movement of a UIImage when using UIPanGestureRecognizer in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage, uipangesturerecognizer

I am working on an application where I allow the user to move a ruler to scroll over a UITableView.  At the moment, the ruler moves just fine except that I would like to restrict it's movement to ONLY the rows of the UITableView, and nothing else.  Unfortunately, at the moment the user is able to scroll the entire table from the top, and go way beyond the bottom of the table to the bottom of the screen.  I have attached an image to show this:

[image]

Here is the relevant code that I have:

```
    - (void)panGestureDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint newCenter  = _imageView.center;

        newCenter.y = [recognizer locationInView:[_imageView superview]].y;

        if (newCenter.y - _imageView.frame.size.height / 2 < self.table.frame.origin.y)
            newCenter.y = self.table.frame.origin.y + _imageView.frame.size.height / 2;

        else if (newCenter.y + _imageView.frame.size.height / 2 > self.table.frame.origin.y + self.table.frame.size.height)
            newCenter.y = self.table.frame.origin.y + self.table.frame.size.height - _imageView.frame.size.height / 2;

        _imageView.center = newCenter;


        if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

            if (newCenter.y == self.table.frame.origin.y + _imageView.frame.size.height / 2) {

                CGPoint topPoint = [recognizer locationInView:_table];
                NSIndexPath *nextRow = [_table indexPathForRowAtPoint:topPoint];
                int currentRow = nextRow.row;

                if (currentRow != 0) {

                    nextRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentRow-- inSection:0];

                    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
                        [_table selectRowAtIndexPath:nextRow animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];

                    }];

                }


            }
            //below is the specific section where I believe is the issue
            else if (newCenter.y == self.table.frame.origin.y + self.table.frame.size.height - _imageView.frame.size.height / 2) {

                CGPoint bottomPoint = [recognizer locationInView:_table];
                NSIndexPath *nextRow = [_table indexPathForRowAtPoint:bottomPoint];
                int currentRow = nextRow.row;

                if (currentRow != [self.tireCode count]-1) {

                    nextRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentRow++ inSection:0];

                    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
                        [_table selectRowAtIndexPath:nextRow animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];

                    }];

                }

            }

        }
```

As I said, I would like the ruler to scroll only the rows of the UITableView, and nothing beyond that.  What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the value of newCenter.y before assigning a value out of your range.
Define a minimum and maximum values to it.

```
float calculatedY = self.table.frame.origin.y + _imageView.frame.size.height / 2;

calculatedY = MAX(calculatedY, MINIMUM_VALUE_HERE);
calculatedY = MIN(calculatedY, MAXIMUM_VALUE_HERE);

newCenter.y = calculatedY;
```